# Calculate me the sum of all withCounts of a ModelCollection

Tags: laravel

I have a ModelCollection of** Model A**. The Model A has a `oneToMany` relation to a **Model B**. In my query I want to know how many relation Model A has to B. This I solve with `countWith()`. I solve this with countWith().

My current problem is that I would also like to add the sum of all single relations to the ModelCollection. How can I do this?

Expected response:

```
items: array: 3 [
  {
  0 => Model A
    attributes: array: 15 [ 
       ...
       modelB_count: 3
    ]
  }, 
  {
  1 => model A
    attributes: array: 15 [ 
       ...
       modelB_count: 1
    ]
  }
]
perPage: 25
...
total: 2
totalAllModel_B_Relations: 4 // It is the sum from 3 + 1
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Hi. please frame your question in a more understanding way. what do you mean by single model relation. show what have you done till now and how your code is. only then someone can show you the right way.

Comment: @PrakharGyawali Thx for comment. I would like to get at response a new key where contains the sum of all single relations. for esample: `totalAllModel_B_Relations: 4 // It is the sum from 3 + 1`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have paginated response.

```
$data = \App\Models\Country::withCount('states')->paginate();
        
$array['data'] = $data;
$array['sum'] = $data->sum('states_count');

return $array;
```